# How to hardcode textures in Metal? How to create textures without loading external assets?

Tags: swift, textures, metal

Although it seems most developers *strive* for the contrary, I like to have as much of my app's content in the code. In Metal, is there a way to load textures from an array of binary data defined in the code? I do not want to load external assets, if possible, but instead, have them hardcoded into the game. Suppose I have this:

```
let ImageData = "?PNG..." // The string contents of a texture file

var Texture:MTLTexture?
```

How to initialize the texture from the `ImageData` without getting any external assets involved?
Also I know this isn't part of the question, but why is this frowned upon?

Comment: Please don't do this. But if you absolutely insist, you'll need to come up with some way of encoding the data into the source file, since you can't just write the literal bytes into a string literal like that. You could use something like Base-64 encoding to turn the image data into a string, then reverse that encoding at runtime and use `MTKTextureLoader`'s `newTextureWithData:options:error:` method to create a texture from the image data. But please, don't do this.

Comment: @warrenm Well in C you can have hexadecimal character constants in strings like `char *x = "\x20\xa5\x76";`. If swift doesn't support that I can define it in C and bridge it to swift. Don't worry about difficulties encoding the image data in the program. Believe me, I got that covered. All I need to know is how to initialize a texture from a buffer containing the image data.

Comment: Well then, I hope my hint is enough to point you in the right direction. Godspeed.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `MTLTexture.replace()`:

```swift
let TextureWidth = 16, TextureHeight = 16 // Change according to your needs
Texture.replace(MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, TextureWidth, TextureHeight), 0, [UInt8]([
     190, 190, 190, 255, // Texture data in raw RGBA format
]), Width*4)
```

Alternatively, you can use `MTKTextureLoader.newTextureWithData:options:error:` as mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62367933/how-to-hardcode-textures-in-metal-how-to-create-textures-without-loading-extern#comment110323863_62367933)